# Getting the redirected url in urllib2

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2

I have a url, and as soon as I click on it, it redirects me to another webpage. I want to get that directed URL in my code with urllib2.

Sample code:

```
link='mywebpage.com'
html = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) library, by default Requests will perform location redirection for all verbs except HEAD.

```
r = requests.get('https://mywebpage.com')
```

or turn off redirect

```
r = requests.get('https://mywebpage.com', allow_redirects=False)
```